# Turning an old ADSL modem into a WIFI adaptor for PC?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, wifi-configuration

My PC does not have a WiFi adapter right now but I have an old ADSL modem.

Is it possible to configure the modem so I can connect it to my PC using a LAN cable and then use it as a WiFi receiver on Windows 10?

Comment: Probably not possible. Why not buy a wifi usb adapter which are quite cheap.

Comment: Depends which one. Probably not, since this became a common feature *after* "old ADSL modem" unless your "old" is quite new.

Comment: on a different note: considering the cheapness of an USB wifi adapter, which will most likely support the newest protocols (read: speed and encryption)). You will most likely not get a good result with your old modem

Comment: I think the OP should be specific about the hardware; otherwise there cannot be a useful answer. For the popular Fritz Box (in Germany) there is a guide (German, maybe use Google translator): https://avm.de/service/wissensdatenbank/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/106_FRITZ-Box-fur-Betrieb-mit-anderem-Router-einrichten/

Comment: @U.Windl ADSL modems provided by the ISP usually have custom firmware and for old ones, you possibly won't even find guides in the wild. Therefore a more general answer can be very useful since it will better help other users with custom devices as well. But credit where credit it due, there would be no harm in additionally specifying the hardware it might lead to a hardware-specific answer as well. But in my view, there is no need to close the question.

Answer (score 7):

It depends. This will only work if your "modem" (I assume you actually have a modem/router/WiFi-Combo) is [WISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Internet_service_provider) capable. If it is you can connect it to a regular WLAN AP. Be aware that this way you'll be using a "second router" between the WiFi and the PC unless you have a pass-through option (which effectively will change the modem to a WLAN bridge).

If it is not WISP capable, you will not be able to connect it to a Wi-Fi (to an AP), in this case, the router will only be able to "create" a Wi-Fi (function as an AP). Then your only choice is, as Tonny correctly suggests, to change the firmware e.g. to openWRT. But this will only work if your old router combo is compatible.

In my opinion, the better choice will be to get a USB-WiFi-adapter, as already suggested by other users. You can get a used WiFi-adapter for as little as $10 and it will need much less time for configuration.

Comment: I've never heard this feature called "WISP capable". Usually it's more like "wireless client mode".

Comment: @user253751 capable of connecting to a WISP (wireless internet service provider), especially in the end consumer market there might be different names to describe the "mode". If you look online you can find ASUS and TP-Link for example using the term.

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple: For the average user this is NO.

A bit longer: Maybe, if you have the skills to write new firmware for the ADSL modem/router.

The ADSL modem is setup as a router with the ADSL as internet side and the WIFI and wired LAN ports as internal side.

What you want to do it to disable the internet side completely and re-configure the router to act as a LAN-Wi-Fi bridge, which requires entirely different firmware for the ADSL modem.

Since that would be an extremely unusual niche application nobody bothers to make such alternative firmware. If you want it you will have to write it yourself which is most likely beyond your skill-set.

Just buy a Wi-Fi adapter (USB or PCIe). They are very cheap and will just work without hassle.

Comment: The existence of OpenWRT kind of disproves the claim that "nobody bothers to make such alternative firmware"... Still, not all products need it in the first place – some home routers do have Wi-Fi 'client' mode built in, although I suspect it's highly uncommon on ADSL modems in particular.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I know about OpenWRT (I worked on some parts of it myself), but OpenWRT can't operate as a bridge. It is still a router. It can do Wifi client mode (which is technically NOT the same thing, it simply uses the WIFI as "internet" side and the wired ports as internal network) on supported routers, but non of those are ADSL routers as far as I know. (I might be mistaken on that part. Never dealt much with ADSL routers.) Anyway... A real Wifi adapter on the PC would be a lot easier for most people.

Comment: It can certainly do bridging in general (out of the box, the "internal network" is literally a bridge between the Ethernet switch and the Wi-Fi AP), what it can't do is ARPNAT / MACNAT that's required for station-mode bridging – but not for lack of trying, it seems; I've already found two different cases of people bothering to write a patch to implement that (e.g. the 'Gargoyle' patch seems to be prominent) and OpenWRT refusing to merge any of them for whatever reason.